# Spring Boot 2 Actuator Metrics Cache

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have some caches

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "myCache")
public class MyService { ... }

@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "myOtherCache")
public class MyOtherService { ... }
```

I get with "/actuator/metrics/cache.gets"

```
{
  "name" : "cache.gets",
  "measurements" : [ {
    "statistic" : "COUNT",
    "value" : 5.0
  } ],
  "availableTags" : [ {
    "tag" : "result",
    "values" : [ "hit", "miss" ]
  }, {
    "tag" : "cache",
    "values" : [ "myCache", "myOtherCache" ]
  }, {
    "tag" : "name",
    "values" : [ "myCache", "myOtherCache" ]
  }, {
    "tag" : "cacheManager",
    "values" : [ "cacheManager" ]
  } ]
}
```

how can I obtain the hit and miss values for myCache and myOtherCache?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the tags as explained here : http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2018/03/13/drill-down-into-spring-boot-actuator-metrics/

```
GET .../actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:myCache
GET .../actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:myOtherCache
```

Comment: Is it possible to show not the actual values but the percentage of overall hits and misses like in old actuator ?

Comment: Thanks for providing this simple example. No clue why such things cannot be simply found in the documentation.